# CSS dropdown menu issue in Safari

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, safari

I've implemented a simple CSS dropdown menu that works perfectly in every browser I've tried except for Safari (on Windows). My page can be seen [here](http://weinstein.com/new/seligmann/kurt-seligmann.html). Within my primary navigation list items, I have an `<li>` class called "drop" that is set to `position:relative` and a div labeled "drop-container" that contains the drop-down menu items and is positioned absolutely with respect to the parent list item. I'm changing `visibility` on hover-- in this case `nav#primary ul li.drop .dropcontainer`-- to `visible` and changing the opacity from 0 to 1 to enable a CSS transition.

I can't figure out for the life of me why this simple menu isn't working in Safari-- any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to operating with display.

```
nav#primary ul li.drop .dropcontainer {display:none;}
nav#primary ul li.drop:hover .dropcontainer {display:block;}
```

Comment: thanks Alex-- that does solve the problem; the only remaining issue is now the CSS transition based on opacity doesn't work. Is there a way to still get the transition working? and is the visibility property just not well-supported in Safari?

Comment: nickpish, It depends on what version of Safari you are using. If it earlier than 6.1 than you need to add -webkit prefix to your rule

Comment: hm, I do have all vendor prefixes specified for the transition including -webkit

Comment: Ok, Than I need to see your code maybe you missed something

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'd really appreciate it-- you can check out my code at the link I provided in my initial post.

Comment: Ah-Ha! I figured it out--- after digging around, I've found that at least certain versions of Safari have issues with opacity transitions when "all" is used instead the specific property to be animated-- in this case, I specified "opacity" and all is working.. perhaps this thread will save someone else a similar headache..